# При нажатии Button создается ее копия в другой активности

Tags: android, button

Помогите, пожайлуйста, имеется проблема: не могу никак найти, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии Button создавалась ее копия в другой активности. Android.

Comment: зачем? можно создать Button в другой Activity и установить ей необходимые свойства размер, отступ, текст, цвет(программно если нужно). Какие-то динамически изменяемые свойства передать через Intent от 1й Activity

Comment: Пожалуйста, напишите, что вы хотите сделать и для чего вам это. Уверен, мы найдем лучшее решение.

Comment: Это как бы кнопка добавление в Избранное(Активити 2)

Answer (score 3):

А что если создать Button изначально в xml, а потом выставлять только ее видимость. Какой-нибудь флаг передавать и в методе

```
onCreate(){
if (flagBookmarks) btn.setVisible()...}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую сегодня, если что, отпишусь.

Answer (score 1):

[Почитайте тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/58-urok-21-sozdanie-i-vyzov-activity).

[Посмотрите: если вам проще смотреть и слушать, так проще тут](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4hMqjMcfA3g&list=PLyfVjOYzujuitvmO3ttzfXFRldfS863RX).

Comment: Попробуй так.